# storage.sync in background script not saving

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Good morning all,

I've been trying to save to chrome local and sync storage from my options page, without success. I read that I needed to store from a popup or background page, so I moved the code to background and messaged it. From the console I can see that my code is being executed, but still when I look in the Application tab in the Inspector, nothing is being saved. Any assistance appreciated:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, callback) {
  if (message.data == "saveFeed") {
    doSave(message.key, message.value);
  };
});

doSave("options", "optionsvalue");


function doSave (key, value) {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({key : value}, function () {
    console.log("backstore.js saved " + value + " with key " + key);
  });
}
```

Comment: The Applications tab doesn't show data stored via chrome.storage API. See [Inspect chrome.storage.sync while debugging Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/32471596)

Comment: Thank you, the storage inspector showed me that I was saving exactly what I thought I was.